# Postman: iterating through a list in a Pre-request Script

Tags: javascript, postman

I've got the following in a postman pre-request script. Currently I have to have one POST for each userlocation, and each POST defines a separate "searchLoc", so the list below would require 4 posts (my original list is 200 locations). I'm wondering if there is a way to iterate through the list with just one POST. Maybe a folder based pre-request script, but can't figure out how to either walk the list, or repeat the same POST 200 times.

```
var userLocations = [["WDC","Washington",38.8976,-76.0476],
["MEX","Mexico City",19.7665,-100.1692],
["MIA","Miami",25.8456,-80.2082],
["SFO","San Francisco",37.8236,-122.4217]];

var searchLoc = "DC";
for ( i=0; i<userLocations.length; i++) {
  if (!userLocations[i].indexOf(searchLoc)) break;
}
var username = userLocations[i][0]+"_"+userLocations[i][1];
var lat = userLocations[i][2];
var lng = userLocations[i][3];

postman.setEnvironmentVariable("username", username);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("lat", lat);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("long", lng);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Newman and write a bash script. In script you can iterate through the list and pass locations to the postman global variables and in the same loop just run the collection.